# Toggle div should hide first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing a CRUD and trying to use some Javascript/JQuery. I have button "Add" where  if it is clicked the div will be shown, I've done this part but the div already showed before you click the add button

Question: How can I hide first the div if it is not yet clicked?

**My View**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add-user">Add</button>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <form id="my-form">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
```

**My JS**

```
$('#add-user').click(function(){
    $('#myDiv').toggle();   
});
```

Comment: You can add `style="display: none"` as an attribute on your `<div>`. Or better yet, create a CSS helper class like `.default-hidden` and use that. It looks like you're using Bootstrap. If you're using Bootstrap 4, it has a utility class `d-none` that you can take advantage of.

Comment: So it is mandatory to put that in my div? I thought it is just an optional..

Comment: Well, `toggle()` does the opposite of the current display attribute, so if you want it to show the first time, you have to start with your element hidden. You could hide it with JavaScript, but the screen will flicker as it draws and hides it on page load.

Comment: I saw too the hide and show function, when should I use hide/show and toggle?

Answer (score 2):

Add in your css

```
myDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

This will make the initial render to hide your div

Comment: So it is mandatory to put that in my div? I thought it is just an optional

Comment: Its not mandatory, there are other ways. You could make call `$('#myDiv').toggle();` when the code is first rendered, you could hide it on css on a different way, you could add another class that hides it. There are many options

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @amine-ramoul & @iagowp said, using *JQuery*
try

```
$('#add-user').on('click', function(){
    $("#myDiv").show();
});
```

And

```
style="display: none"
```

is the correct syntax.

Comment: When should I use show/hide and toggle? is there any advantage/s using show/hide instead toggle?

Comment: show/hide are explicit.  toggle relies entirely on the current state.

Answer (score 1):

juste add display none like this :

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <form id="my-form">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
```